# ошибка в arduino nano при передачи логического 0 или 1

Tags: arduino

```
#include "nRF24L01.h"
#include "RF24.h"

RF24 radio(7,8); // "создать" модуль на пинах 9 и 10 Для Уно
//RF24 radio(9,53); // для Меги

byte address[][6] = {"1Node","2Node","3Node","4Node","5Node","6Node"};  //возможные номера труб

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600); //открываем порт для связи с ПК
  radio.begin(); //активировать модуль
  Serial.print(1);
  radio.setAutoAck(1);         //режим подтверждения приёма, 1 вкл 0 выкл
  Serial.print(2);
  radio.setRetries(0,15);     //(время между попыткой достучаться, число попыток)
  Serial.print(3);
  radio.enableAckPayload();    //разрешить отсылку данных в ответ на входящий сигнал
  Serial.print(4);
  radio.setPayloadSize(32);     //размер пакета, в байтах
  Serial.print(5);
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
  Serial.print(6);
  radio.openReadingPipe(1,address[0]);      //хотим слушать трубу 0
  Serial.print(7);
  radio.setChannel(0x70);
  Serial.print(8);
  radio.setPALevel (RF24_PA_MAX); 
  Serial.print(9);
  radio.setDataRate (RF24_250KBPS); 
  Serial.print(10);
  
  radio.powerUp(); //начать работу
  radio.startListening();  //начинаем слушать эфир, мы приёмный модуль
  radio.printDetails();
}

void loop() {
    byte pipeNo, gotByte;                          
    while( radio.available(&pipeNo)){    // слушаем эфир со всех труб
      radio.read( &gotByte, sizeof(gotByte) );         // чиатем входящий сигнал
//      Serial.println(gotByte);
//      Serial.println(pipeNo);
      if(int(gotByte) == 1){
        digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
        }
      if(int(gotByte) == 0){
        digitalWrite(9, LOW);
        }
   }
}
```

Я пишу проект где мне нужно принять единицу по радио и переключить реле. а при получении 0 выключить реле.

````
#include "nRF24L01.h"     // библиотека радиомодуля
#include "RF24.h"  
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

RF24 radio(9, 10); // "создать" модуль на пинах 9 и 10 Для Уно
//RF24 radio(9,53); // для Меги
SoftwareSerial Bluetooth(2, 3);
byte address[][6] = {"1Node", "2Node", "3Node", "4Node", "5Node", "6Node"}; //возможные номера труб

byte counter;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); //открываем порт для связи с ПК
  Bluetooth.begin(9600); 
  radio.begin(); //активировать модуль
  radio.setAutoAck(1);         //режим подтверждения приёма, 1 вкл 0 выкл
  radio.setRetries(0, 15);    //(время между попыткой достучаться, число попыток)
  radio.enableAckPayload();    //разрешить отсылку данных в ответ на входящий сигнал
  radio.setPayloadSize(32);     //размер пакета, в байтах
  radio.openWritingPipe(address[0]);   //мы - труба 0, открываем канал для передачи данных
  radio.setChannel(0x70);  //выбираем канал (в котором нет шумов!)
  pinMode(7, OUTPUT);
  radio.setPALevel (RF24_PA_MAX); //уровень мощности передатчика. На выбор RF24_PA_MIN, RF24_PA_LOW, RF24_PA_HIGH, RF24_PA_MAX
  radio.setDataRate (RF24_250KBPS); //скорость обмена. На выбор RF24_2MBPS, RF24_1MBPS, RF24_250KBPS
  //должна быть одинакова на приёмнике и передатчике!
  //при самой низкой скорости имеем самую высокую чувствительность и дальность!!

  radio.powerUp(); //начать работу
  radio.stopListening();  //не слушаем радиоэфир, мы передатчик
}

void loop() {
    if(Bluetooth.available())
  {  
//    char c = Bluetooth.read();
//    Serial.println(c);
//    Serial.println(counter);
//    if(c == '1')
//    {
//      counter = 1;
//      digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
//    }
//    if(c == '0'){
//      counter = 0;
//      digitalWrite(7, LOW);
//      }
      digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
//       delay(6000);
  }
  else{
    digitalWrite(7, LOW);
    }
      if (Bluetooth.available()) {
     Serial.write(Bluetooth.read());
     }
  if (Serial.available()) {
     Bluetooth.write(Serial.read());
     }

  radio.write(&counter, sizeof(counter));
}``` вот вторая часть кода у меня на передатчике отсылается но почему-то приёмник то есть первая часть кода не принимает.
````

Comment: в чём ошибка то?

Comment: не знаю в чём причина

Comment: ну так и мы не знаем! а не знаем потому, что вы не описали должным образом, что и как должно работать, и как оно работает по факту

Comment: всё изменил и добавил информации

Comment: попробуйте убрать из кода всё лишнее, оставив только примём/передачу и проверьте. не исключено, что ошибка может быть где-то в условии или банально в питании модуля

Comment: я так пробовал, скорее всего ошибка в логике, так как он пакеты принимает

Comment: а вы уверены, что в `int(gotByte)` именно `1` или `0`?

Comment: да, вот этой командой я отсылаю байт 1 или 0 `radio.write(&counter, sizeof(counter));`

Answer (score 0):

может кому понадобится. все просто, в TX коде нужно указать

void loop() {

radio.powerUp(); //начать работу

и далее ваш код